# Spring-Boot on AppEngine Standard Detect Shutdown

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot, java-8

Using Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE on Google Appengine Standard. Using autoscaling but trying to get some control about creation/destruction of the instances. Need to be able to do some cleanup and would like to log those events.

Any methods in Spring Boot like @Predestroy or ContextClosedEvent don't seem to work on GAE.

According to the documention, it should be possible to detect shutdown of an instance by adding a shutdown hook.

[Documentation LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook)

Have tried to put it in several places without success.

Example as a @Bean:

```
@Bean
public LifecycleManager lifecycleManager() {

    LifecycleManager lifecycle_manager = LifecycleManager.getInstance();

    lifecycle_manager.setShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook() {

        public void shutdown() {

            LifecycleManager.getInstance().interruptAllRequests();

            log.error("Shutdown " + getClassSimpleName() + ".");

        }

    });

    log.warn("Created shutdown hook.");

    return lifecycle_manager;

}
```

Shutdown hook is properly installed, but doesn't get fired when the instance goes down.

Comment: Does it work outside Google App Engine?

Comment: As @Bean it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36462712):

> Shutdown hooks only work for manual scaled instances on the standard runtime (...).

The shutdown hooks simply don't work on automatic and basic scaling.

Comment: Is it still the case? , this is a response from almost a year ago.

Comment: I'm not working with this technology anymore, but a quick look at the docs and the Issue Tracker suggest so ("Status: Won't Fix (Intended behavior)").

Comment: Thank you arudzinska  . I have a strange error when trying also working with manual scaling. Same error for manual and automatic scaling see this https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21980832